# Dropdownlist not showing correct selected value in ASP.NET Repeater Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a few ASP.NET Repeaters that have drop down lists in them and they all need to be populated with the correct information and then display the selected value for each data row it is displaying. In one repeater (`CompanyRepeater`), the correct selected value is chosen. In another repeater (`SoldRepeater`), the correct selected value is NOT chosen. So the drop down list in `CompanyRepeater` does work but the one in `SoldRepeater` does not work. The code is the same for both repeaters and I cannot figure out why the second one is not working. Both drop down lists populate with the correct information but the second repeater does not display the correct selected value. Please help me figure out why the correct selected value is not being selected. Below is my code. Please let me know if there is anymore information needed to help me. Any help is much appreciated. First is my front end code.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CompanyRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="CompanyRepeater_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="CompanyRepeater_ItemCommand">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">
               <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Company</h3>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Event Date:
               <br />
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:Label ID="lblCompID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CompID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">Notes:
               <br />
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" Text='<%#Eval("Notes") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>OldName
               <br />
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtOldNameChange" Text='<%#Eval("OldName") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Country:
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
               <br /> State:
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>New Name
               <br />
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewNameChange" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("NewName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="3" style="width: 50px; float: right;">
               <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateName" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
               <br />
               <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CompID") %>' />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <SeparatorTemplate>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <br />
   </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<hr />
<asp:Repeater ID="SoldRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="SoldRepeater_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="SoldRepeater_ItemCommand">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">
               <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">Sold Event</h3>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Event Date:
               <br />
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtSoldDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EventDate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
               <asp:Label ID="lblCompID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CompID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">Notes:
               <br />
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtSoldNotes" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" Text='<%#Eval("Notes") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>Sold to Company
               <br />
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtSoldTo" Text='<%#Eval("SoldToCompany") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               <br /> Sold to Type
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSoldTo" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2">
               <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CompID") %>' />
               <br />
               <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CompID") %>' />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <SeparatorTemplate>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <br />
   </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is my backend code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _cID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CompID"]);
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      PopulateCompanyRepeater();
      PopulateSoldEvent();
   }
}
private void PopulateCompanyRepeater()
{
   DALAccessData a = new DALAccessData(connString);
   _listInfo = a.GetCompInfo(_cID);
   CompanyRepeater.DataSource = _listInfo;
   CompanyRepeater.DataBind();
}
private void PopulateSoldEvent()
{
   DALSectionAccessData a = new DALSectionAccessData(connString);
   _listEvents = a.GetSoldEvents(_cID);
   SoldRepeater.DataSource = _listEvents;
   SoldRepeater.DataBind();
}
protected void CompanyRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
      DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlCountry");
      DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlState");
      Corp co = (Corp)e.Item.DataItem;
      Corp st = (Corp)e.Item.DataItem;

      SqlDataAdapter sda;
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      try
      {
         using(cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
         {
            string s = "SELECT DISTINCT a.Country_ID, a.CountryName FROM States c INNER JOIN Countries a ON a.Country_ID = c.Country_ID";
            cn.Open();
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(s, cn);
            sda.Fill(ds);
            ddl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddl.DataTextField = "CountryName";
            ddl.DataValueField = "Country_ID";
            ddl.DataBind();
            cn.Close();
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         throw new Exception(ex.Message);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < ddl.Items.Count; i++)
      {
         if (co.Country_ID == Convert.ToInt32(ddl.Items[i].Value))
         {
            ddl.Items[i].Selected = true;
         }
         else
         {
            ddl.Items[i].Selected = false;
         }
      }

      try
      {
         using(cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
         {
            string s = "SELECT DISTINCT StateName, StateID FROM States WHERE Country_ID = " + ddl.SelectedValue;
            cn.Open();
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(s, cn);
            sda.Fill(ds);
            ddl2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddl2.DataTextField = "StateName";
            ddl2.DataValueField = "StateID";
            ddl2.DataBind();
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         throw new Exception(ex.Message);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < ddl2.Items.Count; i++)
      {
         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddl2.Items[i].Value))
         {
            if (st.StateID == Convert.ToInt32(ddl2.Items[i].Value))
            {
               ddl2.Items[i].Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
               ddl2.Items[i].Selected = false;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)CompanyRepeater.Items[0].FindControl("ddlCountry");
   DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)CompanyRepeater.Items[0].FindControl("ddlState");
   ddl2.Items.Clear();
   using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
   {
      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
      {
         cmd.CommandText = "SELECT StateName, StateID FROM States WHERE Country_ID = " + ddl.SelectedValue;
         cmd.Connection = conn;
         conn.Open();
         using(SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
               ListItem _listStates = new ListItem();
               _listStates.Text = sdr["StateName"].ToString();
               _listStates.Value = sdr["StateID"].ToString();
               ddl2.Items.Add(_listStates);
            }
         }
      }
   }
   ddl2.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
   ddl2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select a State", "-1"));
   ddl2.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
protected void SoldRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
   {
      DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlSoldTo");
      int x = ((CorpEvents)e.Item.DataItem).SoldToTypeID;
      //Corp x = (Corp)e.Item.DataItem;

      SqlDataAdapter sda;
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      try
      {
         using(cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
         {
            string s = "SELECT SoldToTypeID, SoldToTypeName FROM SoldToType";
            cn.Open();
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(s, cn);
            sda.Fill(ds);
            ddl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddl.DataTextField = "SoldToTypeName";
            ddl.DataValueField = "SoldToTypeID";
            ddl.DataBind();
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         throw new Exception(ex.Message);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < ddl.Items.Count; i++)
      {
         if (x == Convert.ToInt32(ddl.Items[i].Value))
         {
            ddl.Items[i].Selected = true;
            //i = 9;
         }
         else
         {
            ddl.Items[i].Selected = false;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My data access layer code

```
public List <Corp> GetCompInfo(int a)
{
   List <Corp> _listInfo = new List <Corp> ();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();

   //create the connection and command objects
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection);
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
   //populate the command object
   command.Connection = connection;
   command.CommandText = "SELECT a.CompID, CONVERT(varchar(10), a.Date, 120) AS Date, a.Notes, b.StateID, b.OldName, b.NewName, c.Country_ID FROM NameChange b INNER JOIN CompanyInfo a ON a.CompID = b.CompID INNER JOIN States c ON c.StateID = b.StateID WHERE a.CompID = " + a;

   using(connection)
   {
      using(command)
      {
         connection.Open();
         ds.Load(command.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, new string[] {
            "MyTable"
         });
         dt = ds.Tables["MyTable"];
      }
   }
   foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
      Corp e = new Corp();
      e.CompID = Convert.ToInt32(row["CompID"].ToString());
      e.NewName = row["NewName"].ToString();
      e.OldName = row["OldName"].ToString();
      e.StateID = Convert.ToInt32(row["StateID"].ToString());
      e.Notes = row["Notes"].ToString();
      e.CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(row["Country_ID"].ToString());
      e.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"].ToString());
      e.Date.ToShortDateString();
      _listInfo.Add(e);
   }
   return _listInfo;
}
public List <Corp> GetSoldEvents(int a)
{
   List <Corp> _listInfo = new List <Corp> ();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();

   //create the connection and command objects
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection);
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
   //populate the command object
   command.Connection = connection;
   command.CommandText = "SELECT a.CompID, a.Notes, a.Date, b.SoldToCompany, c.SoldToTypeName, c.SoldToTypeID FROM CompanyInfo a INNER JOIN SoldEvent b ON a.CompID = b.CompID INNER JOIN SoldToType c ON b.SoldToTypeID = c.SoldToTypeID WHERE a.CompID = " + a;

   using(connection)
   {
      using(command)
      {
         connection.Open();
         ds.Load(command.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, new string[] {
            "MyTable"
         });
         dt = ds.Tables["MyTable"];
      }
   }

   foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
      Corp e = new Corp();
      e.CompID = Convert.ToInt32(row["CompID"].ToString());
      e.SoldToCompany = row["SoldToCompany"].ToString();
      e.SoldToTypeName = row["SoldToTypeName"].ToString();
      e.SoldToTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(row["SoldToTypeID"].ToString());
      e.Notes = row["Notes"].ToString();
      e.EventDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"].ToString());
      e.EventDate.ToShortDateString();
      _listInfo.Add(e);
   }
   return _listInfo;
}
```

Comment: When does this happen? On first load, postback, or selectedIndexChange?

Comment: This happens on first load

Comment: When you say "correct selected value is NOT chosen", is the first item selected (default) or is a different (incorrect) item selected in the list?

Comment: The first item is selected(default)  which is not the correct value. For example: if I have options 1, 2, 3 and option 2 is supposed to be selected, it will display option 1 as the selected value instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, your method of setting the selected value is rather cumbersome. This entire section of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ddl.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if (x == Convert.ToInt32(ddl.Items[i].Value))
   {
      ddl.Items[i].Selected = true;
      //i = 9;
   }
   else
   {
      ddl.Items[i].Selected = false;
   }
}
```

Can be replaced with a single line:

```
ddl.SelectedValue = x.ToString();
```

In addition, once you do find the matching value you continue to loop on the items, rather than exiting out of the loop.

Try these changes, they may solve the problem for you.

A few other items that I noticed:

1. The code to retrieve the `SoldToType` is called for each item in the
   repeater. I would suggest retrieving this data once and referencing
   it for each item, rather than going to the db each time.
2. Your SQL code is wide open to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries, like so:

   ```
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT StateName, StateID FROM States WHERE Country_ID = @CountryID";
   ...
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CountryID", ddl.SelectedValue);
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. Also, thank you for your suggestions. I appreciate it all.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to help :)